# fs.appendFile does not append to new line

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to append a string to a new line instead of the end of the current line.

Right now, I have a following code.

```
fs.appendFile(`data/battle-log.csv`, `${new Date().toLocaleString()},1,0,0\r\n`, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I open the output in notepad app, and I am getting this...

```
2021/11/7 16:03:15,1,0,02021/11/7 16:16:18,1,0,02021/11/7 16:28:44,1,0,0
```

I want this instead

```
2021/11/7 16:03:15,1,0,0
2021/11/7 16:16:18,1,0,0
2021/11/7 16:28:44,1,0,0
```

## EDIT

Oddly enough however, when I open the csv file in notepad, and remove the *seconds* from Date string like this...

```
2021/11/7 16:03:15,1,0,02021/11/7 16:16:18,1,0,0
2021/11/7 16:28,1,0,0   // <- remove 'seconds' from Date string
```

The next time I run the program, it adds the string to a new line.

```
2021/11/7 16:03:15,1,0,02021/11/7 16:16:18,1,0,0
2021/11/7 16:28,1,0,0
2021/11/7 16:41:23,1,0,0  // <- added to a new line somehow
```

Comment: `fs.write()` instead?

Comment: Have you checked working with text files? It should work, it there any error or just adds the `\r\n` to the csv file?

Comment: No there's no error or anything nor adds `\r\n`. Added the output I am getting in the question

Comment: What editor are you using to show this file? Works fine here ...

Comment: @derpirscher  just a regular windows notepad...

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is, that you have some character between `\r` and `\n` (and yes, there are things like invisible characters). Try removing that line and completely *retype* it (do not copy and paste)

Comment: You could also try opening your file with a HEX editor which shows the bytes in your file. You should find the sequence `13 10` (or `0D 0A`)  in your file (without any other byte between them), which stands for the charaters `\r\n`

Comment: You can also try to do something like the following `fs.readFile("data/battle-log.csv", (err, data) => console.log(data))` which will print you the bytes of your file. You should again be able to find the sequence `0d 0a` there, which denotes a proper windows linebreak ...

Comment: If you don't find that linebreak sequence in the bytes, you are using different souce, than you posted here. Because if I c&p your code, I get proper linebreaks ...

Comment: @derpirscher I actually changed it to just `\n` and it started working... and after I got your comment, I switched back to `\r\n` to replicate the same issue but somehow started working properly too for that too. I looked that up in hex editor and it was `0d 0a` sitting there..

Comment: Honestly I am not too sure what exactly the issue was..

Comment: @koyamashinji Most probably a subtle typo. You still have one of the files, where it didn't seem to work? Can you check this with the hex editor too?

Comment: @derpirscher unfortunately its overwritten. I'll look into it more